# Create ServiceBus topic if it doesn't already exist

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

Microsoft has updated their .NET ServiceBus client library, and their documentation is currently split between the old [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) package and the new [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) package. I like the new package, as its a lot cleaner and has less dependencies. In the old package, we had methods like the following:

```
if (!namespaceManager.TopicExists(topicName))
{
    var topic = new TopicDescription(topicName);
    namespaceManager.CreateTopic(topic);
}
```

The documentation for creating a topic programmatically still uses the old package, with code like the above. The `NamespaceManager` class is not available in the new package, so how can I achieve the equivalent of this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Update Jan 2022

[Microsoft recommends to use ServiceBusAdministrationClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-management-libraries#manage-using-service-bus-client-libraries) in their latest package Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.

```
const string Topic = "<YourTopic>";    

// Create the topic if it doesn't exist
var adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(ConnectionString);
if (!await adminClient.TopicExistsAsync(Topic))
    await adminClient.CreateTopicAsync(Topic);
```

And similar for creating subscriptions.

Thanks to Quan for the update

---

## Original answer

On the Github Repo [azure-service-bus-dotnet](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet), they explains how to manage Service Bus entities :

- [Can I manage Service Bus entities with this library?](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet#can-i-manage-service-bus-entities-with-this-library):

> The standard way to manage Azure resources is by using [Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview). In order to use functionality that previously existed in the .NET Framework Service Bus client library, you will need to use the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus` library. This will enable use cases that dynamically create/read/update/delete resources.

There is a sample on how to use this library:

- [Service Bus Management Library Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-bus-dotnet-management)

you need to install these packages:

- Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus
- Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager
- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

The interesting part for you if you want to create a topic. Note that you don't need to check if the topic exists. Azure resource manager only updates the resource if it already exists.

```
// On you've got the ServiceBusManagementClient
ServiceBusManagementClient sbClient = ...

sbClient.Topics.CreateOrUpdateAsync("resource group name", "namespace name", "topic name", 
    new Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Models.SBTopic());
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I skimmed over the readme and didn't pick up that "manage service bus entities" equates to "create/read/update topics and subscriptions". What's the deal with the "resource group name"? I assume this is the same as resource groups I see in the Azure portal, but doesn't that make code like this a bit easier to break if the resources are shifted around in Azure?

Comment: Yes it is the name of the resource group on Azure. I guess it depends if you are using multiple resource groups. Maybe you can ask another question to deal with it.

Answer (score 9):

In .NET Core you can use `ManagementClient` to do so, which is easier comparing to namespace manager.

```
try
{   
    await managementClient.GetTopicAsync(topicName);
}
catch (MessagingEntityNotFoundException)
{   
    await managementClient.CreateTopicAsync(new TopicDescription(topicName) { EnablePartitioning = true });
}

try
{
    await managementClient.GetQueueAsync(queueName);
}
catch (MessagingEntityNotFoundException)
{
    await managementClient.CreateQueueAsync(new QueueDescription(queueName) { EnablePartitioning = true });
}
```

[See azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/65](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/65)

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer was in 2017 so there is an update on how we create a topic on Azure Service Bus as today 1/13/2022.

Microsoft recommends to use ServiceBusAdministrationClient in their latest package Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.

Install NuGet package: Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

And here is how you will create a new topic:

```
const string Topic = "<YourTopic>";    

// Create the topic if it doesn't exist
var adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(ConnectionString);
if (!await adminClient.TopicExistsAsync(Topic))
    await adminClient.CreateTopicAsync(Topic);
```

And similar for creating subscriptions.

This answer is based on this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-management-libraries#manage-using-service-bus-client-libraries

Comment: Hi Quan, thanks for the update. I can't accept two answers on one question, so I'm going to add the contents of this as an update to Thomas' answer

Answer (score 1):

There's also a future option if you can wait - NamespaceManager as a standalone package described in the [following issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/65). The [options it will support](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/65#issuecomment-338874419) are listed in the issue as well.

- Get - limited to exists check and give metadata back
- GetRuntimeInformation (Gets all counts and last state, Approximate count, accurate within 10s)
- GetQueueNames, GetTopicNames (List entity names)
- Create entity
- Delete entity
- Update (Need details on what metadata to update, can be done during implementation)
- FindOrCreate (Upsert - queue doesn't exists create it)
- UpdateOrCreate (Upsert)

If you'd like the ease of `NamespaceManager`, then worth following the issue.